# Appengine Logging: How to query a request-path prefix

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

In Google Appengine Stackdriver logging control panel, I was able to query logs by path-prefix with regex queries: "path:/abc/def/.*" now this filter does not show any results anymore.

The [documentation from Hell](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs) for this interface from Hell has no examples that I find useful. Simple text searches have too many false positives. Did anyone figure out how to make request-path regex or prefix queries in that panel like the following?

Request-path: /abc/def/.* 
Request-path: /abc/def/.*.jpg

**Update:** I figured out the first part: They changed it to "path:/abc/def" without regex. However this thing is crippled, it seems to only search back 7 days into the past?

Answer (score 1):

7 days is the max logs age in the (default) Basic Tier. From [Quota Policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quota-policy):

```
Maximum limit                Value

Retention of log entries     30 days (Premium Tier)
                             7 days (Basic Tier)
```

Comment: Great! Logs are becoming a premium feature that lacks the functionality of grep? Seems like a big step backwards. After following the link in "Quota Policy" to my cloud console's API page. I could not find any page related to costs, usage or ability to upgrade. Instead I found that my pure app-engine project is heavily using the compute engine api now, but that is off-topic?!